# Why ActionEvent.getActionCommand() returns null?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I have a problem with F keys(F1, F2, etc.). I want to add action to F keys and I want to handle it all in one event. That's why I wanted to use the getActionCommand method, but it always returns null. However if I use numpad keys it works as intended. Thanks

Not working code with F keys:
Code:

```
    private void setKeyBindings() {
    AbstractAction numberAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
        }
    };

    InputMap inputMap = this.editButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        String text = String.valueOf(i);

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F" + text), text);
        this.editButton.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
    }
}
```

Working numpad code:

```
    private void setKeyBindings() {
    AbstractAction numberAction = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            System.out.println(ae.getActionCommand());
        }
    };

    InputMap inputMap = this.editButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String text = String.valueOf(i);

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD" + text), text);
        this.editButton.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why I suggest using a re-usable Action which was seeded with the value/information you needed for each key ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to use the getActionCommand method, but it always returns null

Function keys don't generate a character.

If you want to know which key was pressed when you use function keys or other keys that don't generate characters then you need to get a little fancier:

```
class SimpleAction extends AbstractAction
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
        KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)queue.getCurrentEvent();
        String keyStroke = ke.getKeyText( ke.getKeyCode() );
        String number = keyStroke.substring(1);
        System.out.println( number );

    }
}
```

The real problem is that you are trying to use the function keys to perform the same function as just using the number key. I see no need to use a function key to simulate the typing of a key when you can just type the key.